# Update Rows in the database with LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**ASP Core vs MsSQL**

*I checked many answers for the similar question but didn't find an answer.*

Student table and Course table are joined with the junction table StudentCourse:

```
Student      StudentCourse       Course
=========    ============        =======
PK | ID      FK | StudentID       PK | ID
   | Name    FK | CourseID           | Name
```

**I want to update/change CourseId in the junction StudentCourse table** for a student who decided to change his course.
My context class:

```
    public class AppDbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CourseModel> CourseModels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<StudentModel> StudentModels { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
                .HasKey(t => new { t.StudentId, t.CourseId });

            builder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.Student)
                .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourse)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.StudentId);

            builder.Entity<StudentCourse>()
                .HasOne(sc => sc.Course)
                .WithMany(s => s.StudentCourse)
                .HasForeignKey(sc => sc.CourseId);
        }
    }
```

My controller's method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult ChangeCourse(CourseModel newCourse)
        {
            // I want to get course Id for this student
            Guid courseId = (from student in context.StudentModels
                             join cours in context.CourseModels on student.Id equals studentId
                             where cours.Id == oldCourseId
                             select cours.Id).SingleOrDefault();

            // Change course Id
            courseId = newCourse.Id;

            context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction();
        }
```

According to [Microsoft FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-update-rows-in-the-database)  there are three steps to update a row in the database:

> 1. Query the database for the row to be updated.
> 2. Make desired changes to member values in the resulting LINQ to SQL object.
> 3. Submit the changes to the database.

So I follow these steps:

> 1. Query the database for the row to be updated.

```
Guid courseId = (from student in context.StudentModels
                 join cours in context.CourseModels on student.Id equals studentId
                 where cours.Id == oldCourseId
                 select cours.Id).SingleOrDefault();
```

> 2. Make desired changes to member values in the resulting LINQ to SQL object.

```
oldCourseIdd = newCourse.Id;
```

> 3. Submit the changes to the database.

```
context.SaveChanges();
```

But **it doesn't save changes**. I don't understand **why**?

Comment: commit??????????

Comment: What is this: `oldCourseIdd`?

Comment: Just being pedantic here. The *Q* in *LINQ* stands for *query*, There is no *U* that stands for *update*. Generally we don't use *LINQ* to update things we use it to query things `</PedanticismOver>`

Comment: "Make desired changes to member values in the resulting LINQ to SQL object." the code you have posted simply does **not** do that.Where does `oldCourseIdd` come from? is this a " resulting LINQ to SQL object" ?

Comment: Is this really LINQ to SQL? Looks more like entity framework to me; LINQ to SQL is a very different thing to EF and only works with SQL server, whereas you've tagged mysql. I get the feeling you're following a wrong tutorial by reading that FAQ; the code works for query because EF uses LINQ, but it's not LtS, so don't follow LtS tutorials if you're using EF

Comment: @MongZhu I fixed. Mistake was only here not in real code in VS.

Comment: @TheGeneral [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/how-to-update-rows-in-the-database) It looks like we can update rows, Microsoft says.

Comment: @CaiusJard my bad, typos. The project database is **Microsoft SQL**. The ORM I use is EF Core.

Comment: Have a read of https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/updating-many-to-many-relationships-in-entity-framework-core/

Comment: @mr.Sam_Nihao, does my answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please accept it as an answer, it will help others who have the same problem, if not, please tell me your problem.

Comment: @YongqingYu It doesn't help. Because there is no DbSet<StudentCourse> in my context. So I don't have direct access to this table. I'm trying to do this code:
StudentModel student = studentModel.GetStudentById(studentId); 
         student.StudentCourse.Remove(new StudentCourse { StudentId = student.Id, CourseId = oldCourseId });        student.StudentCourse.Add(new StudentCourse { StudentId = student.Id, CourseId = course.Id });        studentModel.SaveChanges();
But this code doesn't remove, instead it adds one more course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your current table relationship, if you want to update the intermediate table, my suggestion is to **delete the data that needs to be updated first, and then perform the operation of adding row.**

And as mentioned in the reply above, you should not use the linq method to update, but should be based on the database entity.

Try these code to achieve :

```
            var data = context.StudentCourse.Where(x => x.StudentID == studentId  && x.CourseID == oldCourseId).FirstOrDefault();
            context.StudentCourse.Remove(data);
            
           StudentCourse newdata= new StudentCourse()
            {
                StudentID = studentId,
                CourseID = newCourse.Id
            };
            context.StudentCourse.Add(newdata);
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The problem is in my context there is no DbSet<StudentCourse>. That's the problem.

Comment: Finally I've just added  DbSet<StudentCourse>.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't select primitives. It's not trackable by EF. You need to select the `StudentCourse` entity. Then you will be able to set it's `CourseID` and then save changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is my context class doesn't have `StudentCourse` entity as you can see above. I'm trying to change the row in the junction table without direct access to it. 

I can do it in SQL Management Studio with this command:
`UPDATE StudentCourse SET CourseId = '9A414E30-DA37-48ED-105E-08D8129A967A' WHERE StudentId = 'A1F38C12-AE65-464C-C489-08D814F4CDDC'`
But how to do it in VS?
I tried this code:
`context.StudentModels.FromSqlRaw("UPDATE StudentCourse SET CourseId = {0} WHERE StudentId = {1}", course.Id, studentIdForAll);`
But it doesn't work as well.

Comment: I understand it doesn't work because I need to use `StudentCourse` entity instead of `StudentModels`. So it seems like I HAVE TO use `StudentCourse` entity to make changes. But there must be another way to do it.

Comment: EF understands when there is Student and Course entities that are many:many how to split them with middle man table, and Student has list of Course/Course has list of Student.. if you want to change Course for some Student, remove a Course from his list and add another course then save

Comment: naturally, if you add a DbSet for StudentCourse then you can manipulate it, but without it you should to load eg a student with all his courses, then remove the one you don't want and add the one you do. It is perhaps this this is the problem; you're focused on trying to make an update; focus on a delete and insert instead; it's how you would do it in a c# object sense (you would remove one course and add another, you wouldn't find a course and try changing its id to that of a different course)

Comment: @CaiusJard Thank you. Your comment is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Like Online123321 wrote: You need entity insead of primitives.
Also update requres:

```
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

**Update**
EntityState.Modified is no longer required - sorry my bad.

If your table is not in a context maybe you can try to execute SQL directly?:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(query)
```

Comment: Is it really necessary? I thought the change tracker detected changes to objects it had supplied, and this kind of hacking is only necessary if (for example) you're making a new object but want EF to treat it as if it's an updated one

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I saw that answer as well. Microsoft says it's not necessary. At least I didn't find opposite statement.